# Annoying cmd windows on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, wscc

I am using Windows 7 on my PC that is linked with Active directory.

When I log in, I keep getting many cmd screens opening and closing and I can't do anything.

I don't know what happened if this was caused from installing software from a few days ago and I don't know if it's caused by a virus (my antivirus didn't report anything).

If i switch user and log with my admin account, it also happens again.

When I go back to the old screen by switching user again, the annoying cmd windows are not there.

How can I fix this problem?

I managed to get print screen the problem:

[image]

Comment: If it started just after you installed some applications, why not try uninstalling each in safe mode until the problem goes away? Then you've found your culprit.

Comment: actually i restarted after 3 weeks and installed many apps. so i am not sure which app it was. i can't remove all the apps as i have done many work on few of them

Comment: why don't you check the apps which start with you OS? maybe you'll find something suspicious there.

Comment: @DavidDai how can i check that

Comment: @user191542 as far as I know,  CCleaner is a nice piece of software which can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Open msconfig by typing msconfig in run and check what all softwares you have in your startup. Uncheck all the soft wares you don't need to be up and running when you are starting your computer. One of these software may be running some commands at startup. You can also try disabling other software if the issue still exists after removing unwanted software. [image: MSCONFIG]